# Relation between slope of a function and its derivative

Tags: derivatives

What is the relation between the slope of a function and the derivative of that function? I was introduced to the idea of derivatives, which is basically the the concept of rise and run, the increase in value of the function in y axis over the increase of value on x axis. But it's the same for slopes as well right? So can I say that the derivative of a function at a point is basically the slope of the function itself?

Comment: The derivative of a function $f$ at a point $t$ is the slope of the tangent line to the graph of $f$ at $(t,f(t))$.

Comment: To hammer the point, I tell all my calculus students the following: "the derivative is slope." And then we repeat it like some sort of chant. The derivative at a point is just the slope of the tangent line.

Comment: They are the same thing (where the functions is derivable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative can be a lot. It has a direction in which we measure a change, a location at which we do it, and what makes the derivative a local quantity, a function of which we measure a change, and finally a slope which is the change. So it depends on what we put focus on. My personal favorite of looking at it is by the Weierstraß formula:
$$
f(x_0+v)=f(x_0)+ D_{x_0}(f)\cdot v + r(v)
$$
where $x_0$ is the location, $f$ the (differentiable) function, $v$ the direction, $f'(x_0)=D_{x_0}(f)$ the derivative, i.e. the linear approximation at $f,$ the tangent, and $r(v)$ the error we make by such an approximation. The remainder may not have a linear term for otherwise this would add to the already given linear term $D_{x_0}(f)\cdot v.$ This condition reads thus
$$
\lim_{v \to 0}\dfrac{r(v)}{\|v\|}=0
$$
I like that definition because it contains all relevant quantities, and their relevant properties, especially the linearity of $D_{x_0}(f),$ and allows generalizations in all directions, e.g. tangent bundles.

In that setup, we get the derivative $D_{x_0}(f)$ as a function of location $x_0,$ or as an operator $D_{x_0}$ on the function, and last but not least $D_{x_0}(f)\cdot v$ as the slope in direction $v.$

It is a good exercise to show that Weierstraß's formula is equivalent to the common definition via limits (a sequence of secants that converge to a tangent), and to check those quantities at an easy example like $f(x)=x^3+x.$  The crucial point is, that we need all these perspectives in physics and all are usually called just a derivative.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is the slope of the tangent line to a function at a certain point. For example, the derivative of $f(x)=x^2$ is $f'(x)=2x$, so at $x$-value $k$ the slope of the line tangent to $f(x)$ at $x=k$ is $f'(k)=2k$.

We generally use slope for lines and derivatives for more complex curves. However, they are really just the same thing. The derivative of a line $y=ax+b$ is $y'=a$, which is the slope i.e., a line has a constant derivative. But for functions that do not have a constant slope, we define the derivative in terms of  the $x$-value, such as the above example with $f(x)=x^2$.

Another way to think about derivatives and slopes is that they are the *rate of change* of the function at a certain point. A line describes motion at a constant rate, so its slope is constant. Other functions do not have a constant rate of change, so their slope(derivative) is defined in terms of $x$.

**tl;dr**, they are the same, but slopes are more commonly used with lines and derivatives with functions that do not have a constant rate of change, but they are  describing the same thing.